# How much data is send during data update in Blazor Server?

Tags: blazor

Hello i have blazor server application, and table ~1k rowsk 20 columns full off strings. I update one cell how much data will be send to client during update? Whole table or just this one cell value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read on how Blazor works it is keeping a RenderTree on the server. When state changes, the  diff DOM is calculated and only the difference is sent over SignalR. So doing simple accounting, the data sent should be the change in the render tree plus protocol overhead. But please corrent me if I am wrong.